# ImageJ - converting a 8-bit image to "RGB color"

Tags: image, colors, 3d, imagej, color-mapping

I have an 8-bit image, which contains 4 patterns (labelled as 1, 2, 3 and 4).  I would like to display this image in "ImageJ 3D Viewer", with a colour assigned to each of these patterns.  "ImageJ 3D Viewer" takes a "RGB Color" image, therefore I first loaded the image (in ANALYZE format) to ImageJ, following by assigning a colour to each number (of 1, 2, 3, 4) using "edit LUT". The image then showed exactly the colours I'd like to have.  When I converted the image from 8-bit to "RGB Color" by changing the image type, the colours changed completely...

How could I reserve the colours selected for the 8-bit image after transferring it to RGB?  Or is there a simpler way to assign colours to a 8-bit image and have it displayed on the 3D viewer?

Many thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution - may not be the easiest.

I first saved the 8-bit image, after adding the colours, as an "Animated Gif", opened it and displayed it in 3DViewer.